# what is the difference between a function and an arrow function that calls a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
 return {
  buyCake: () => dispatch(buyCake())
 }
}
```

When I run my program by changing the third line to

```
buyCake: dispatch(buyCake())
```

it doesn't work. What is the difference between these two approaches and why do you need the `() =>`

Comment: The second version calls `dispatch(buyCake())` immediately, the first is a function that *will* call it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
buyCake: () => dispatch(buyCake())
```

This will declare `buyCake` to be a function that takes no arguments, and calls `dispatch` in its body; but `buyCake` itself won't be called until *you explicitly call it*.

It's more or less conceptually equivalent to:

```
function buyCake() {
    dispatch(buyCake());
}
```

I say conceptually because there are some technical differences between regular functions and arrow functions (a.k.a. lambdas, lambda expressions); see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more info.

On the other hand

```
buyCake: dispatch(buyCake())
```

will set `buyCake` to the *result* of the call to `dispatch` (`dispatch` will be called *immediately*, right there).

It's the same as the difference between:

```
const getSinPI = () => Math.sin(Math.PI);   // a function named `getSinPI`
getSinPI();                                 // returns approx. 0
```

and

```
const sinPI = Math.sin(Math.PI);   // a variable storing the result (approx. 0)
```

The [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) function returns an object containing, as properties, ad-hoc wrapper functions that you defined, that perform calls to dispatch in some way that makes sense for your application. This object is then used to place these functions on the `props` object (the different dispatch calls are "mapped" onto these wrappers - thus the name). This is so that you can make use of `dispatch` in a more convenient way, using wrapper functions with names that more closely reflect what your application is doing.